# Apache Lucene 6 QueryParser range query is not working with IntPoint

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 6 new `IntPoint` and I want to do some range search

Using `IntPoint.newRangeQuery` the search works and the correct documents are returned, however when I'm using `QueryParser` (classic) or the new `StandardQueryParser` nothing is returned.

```
// This works
Query query =  IntPoint.newRangeQuery("duration",1,20);
System.out.println(query);

//This doesn't work
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("name", analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse("duration:[1 TO 20]");
System.out.println(query);

//This doesn't work
StandardQueryParser queryParserHelper = new StandardQueryParser();
Query query = queryParserHelper.parse("timestamp:[1 TO 20]", "timestamp");
System.out.println(query);



// In all 3 cases it prints: timestamp:[1 TO 20]
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, and I wouldn't say you are missing anything, really. QueryParser doesn't have any support for IntPoint fields, or any other numeric (PointValues) field types. Range queries in QueryParser syntax will always generate a `TermRangeQuery`, which will search for that field based on lexicographic order in the inverted index, which will not be work for searching PointValues fields. Generating these using `IntPoint.newRangeQuery` and similar methods is the correct thing to do.